# Getting pyplot NOT to plot nan values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list [np.nan, np.nan, ... ,1,...  np.nan, np.nan].
I create the list x = [np.nan] x 100 and then replace some elemnt in the middle with a number

I want to plot a graph that ignores all the np.nan values.
However, when I plot such a graph, I get np.nan plotted as some large value instead of a discontinued string.

Is there a way to solve this?

```
data1 = [np.nan] * 5 
for index in range(3): 
    #BEFORE_REPAIR_HYD_OIL_PRESSURE_SYS_A is a dataframe 
    data1[index] = BEFORE_REPAIR_HYD_OIL_PRESSURE_SYS_A.values[index] 
    data1arr = np.array(data1) 
    plt.plot(data1arr) 
    plt.show()
```

Comment: @JohanC Yep (meet word quota)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't happen to me when I do this

```
plt.plot([np.nan]*100 + [2] + [np.nan]*100)
```

I get a correct graph. Can you share your code ?

Comment: data1 = [np.nan] * 5
for index in range(3):

#BEFORE_REPAIR_HYD_OIL_PRESSURE_SYS_A is a dataframe

  data1[index] = BEFORE_REPAIR_HYD_OIL_PRESSURE_SYS_A.values[index]
data1arr = np.array(data1)

plt.plot(data1arr)
plt.show()

Comment: post an example of the data also